# oracle: deferring Foreign Key checks not working

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

oracle: deferring Foreign Key checks not working. e.g.,

```
create table Foo (id number(20,0), name varchar(20), 
    primary key(id));
create table Bar (id number(20,0), name varchar(20), 
    primary key(id),
    constraint FK1 foreign key (id) references Foo (id));

insert into Foo(id,name) values(1, 'foo');
insert into Bar(id,name) values(1, 'bar');
```

delete data:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

delete from Foo;
delete from Bar;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE;
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281078/oracle-sql-defer-vs-disable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle sql defer VS disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281078/oracle-sql-defer-vs-disable)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't defer a constraint if it is `NOT DEFERRABLE`. A constraint can be either deferrable or not, but the default (if you don't explicitly specify either way) is `NOT DEFERRABLE`.

In your sample code, add the keyword `deferrable` right after the foreign key constraint definition, and then run everything again. It will work as expected.

That is: Edit the following line of code

```
constraint FK1 foreign key (id) references Foo (id));
```

to

```
constraint FK1 foreign key (id) references Foo (id) deferrable);
```